# Can't resume editor running as root

Tags: linux, bash, process, sudo

For years, when I have been working over an SSH connection, I will run `sudo vi ...` to edit a config file.  If I need to do something on the command-line, I'll hit Ctrl+Z to suspend the editor, do stuff, then `fg` to get back to it.

But this is no longer working as expected (as of Ubuntu 14.04 as far as I can tell).  The editor gets suspended just fine, but the first time I try to resume it's as though nothing happens (or perhaps it resumes momentarily but then suspends again).  If I try `fg` a second time, the editor appears to resume, but any keys I press are just echoed to the console.  But pressing Ctrl+Z at this point does suspend it and return me to the shell.

I can't figure out how to regain control of the editor.  I usually have to just `sudo kill` it by process ID (`kill %1` throws back "operation not permitted", as I would expect since the editor is running as root).

Please do not suggest using `screen` and/or separate terminals, as I already do this.  I would like to know if there is a solution to this specific problem since hitting Ctrl+Z is such a deep-seated habit that I keep doing it without thinking about it.  Did Ubuntu recently change some security model?

**Update**

I still haven't figured out this problem, but I think it has something to do with suspending nested processes.  I'm not sure if it's specific to sudo.  I haven't been able to reproduce it reliably, but this is the sequence that causes it most often:

1. `sudo vi`*`filename`*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend vi
3. `vi`*`another-filename`*
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
5. `fg 1` to attempt to resume vi running as root. At this point, the shell will simply say `[1]+ Stopped    sudo vi filename`.  Trying `fg 1` again will appear to resume vi, but any keystrokes will simply be echoed to the console.

What appears to be happening is that when I suspend the `sudo vi`, both the `sudo` and `vi` processes are stopped.  When I `fg` the first time, only `sudo` is resumed.  When I `fg` the second time, `sudo` is stopped, but `vi` is resumed.  Under normal circumstances, both processes should be resumed.

Comment: Hi Brian I cannot reproduce your problem with 14.04.1 LTS. It seems to suspend and resume normally. (VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.4.52. `type vi` gives `/usr/bin/vi`). Just a try: check the integrity of the package `debsum vim`.